# how to adding error handler in slim3 middleware

Tags: slim, middleware, slim-3

I started a project with slim3 framework. In my project I wrote a route group called `admin` for administrators.

```
$app->group('/admin', function () use ($app) {
    $app->add( new AdminMiddleWare() );
    $app->get('/books/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        ...
    });
});
```

any of administrators should send a GET token for validation .
I want to create a middleware for checking admins tokens and if the token not set or is invalid display 403 error.

the Middleware class :

```
class AdminMiddleWare
{
    /**
     * Example middleware invokable class
     *
     * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request  PSR7 request
     * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface      $response PSR7 response
     * @param  callable                                 $next     Next middleware
     *
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     */
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        ???
    }
}
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there's a small improvement that you can do to the way you're adding the middleware.

```
$app->group('/admin', function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/books/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        ...
    });
})->add( new AdminMiddleWare() );
```

Attach the middleware to the group not to the entire app.

As for your question, you'll have the query params available in the request object.
i.e. for an URL like `example.com/admin/books/12?token=sf342ad` you will have `$params['token'] == 'sf342ad'`

```
public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
{
    $params = $request->getQueryParams();
}
```

It might be easier to add the token as part of the route as you can generate the URL using reverse routing:

```
$app->group('/admin/{token}', function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/books/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
        ...
    })->setName('admin-book');
});
```

By doing it like this you'll have a `token` key in the `$args` array and it will match URLs like `example.com/admin/sf342ad/books/1`

And you can later build the route without hardcoding much:

```
$app->getContainer()->get('router')->pathFor('admin-book', ['token' =>'your token', 'id' => 'book id'])
```